# Forcing regex to ignore detection depending on preposition

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regex, which will detect usernames mentioned in a string. The usernames can look like "username", "username[0-9]", "adm-username", "adm-username[0-9]".

As of now, I have this: `\b(adm\-){0,1}username[0-9]{0,1}\b` (link: https://regexr.com/4at34)

The problem is with adm-. If the preposition is aadm-username, the regex still detects 'username', I want it to fail. Any tips how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: You want to match any username only with `adm-` prefix or with no prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace `\b` by `[\w-]` in your case.

Also, don't match the boundaries.

And finally, don't match intermediate groups, make a single big group for your matches.

### Demo

[`(?<![\w-])((?:adm-)?username\d?)(?![\w-])`](https://regex101.com/r/wJKkwy/2/)

```
[v] username 
[v] username2 
[v] adm-username 
[v] adm-username2 
[x] aadm-username 
[x] aadm-username2
```

### Explanation

```
(?<![\w-])              # negative lookbehind, only match if no word character or hyphen is present
(
    (?:adm-)?           # non-matching group containing adm- literally once or none, will be matched in the greater group
    username\d?      # literally matching username and a digit, once or none
)
(?![\w-])               # negative lookahead, only match if no word character or hyphen is present
```

Comment: Would you mind to 'dissect' the regex with me?
Just to see if I understand it correctly.

    (?<![\w-]) -- must not have a word ending with - in front of it.

    ((?:adm\-){0,1} -- checks if the group contains adm-? Not sure about this part.

    username[0-9]{0,1}) -- matching the username itself.

    (?![\w-]) -- must not have a word behind itself.

Comment: @Jlisk Sure, I'll do it later within the day if you don't mind

Comment: @Jlisk I added a little bit of explanation

Comment: Thank you for expanding the answer.
About not matching the boundaries, I take it it is better to use lookahead/lookbehind to detect end of the word?